I'm having difficulty definining a property in Coq, not sure how to approach
I've implemented a proof system from a paper in Coq, as shown below.
Term proof System
Require Import Ensembles.

Definition Var := nat.
Definition Name := nat.

Inductive Term: Type :=
| VarTerm (v: Var)
| PrivKeyTerm (k: Name)
| PubKeyTerm (k: Name)
| PairTerm (t1 t2: Term)
| PrivEncTerm  (t: Term) (k: Name)
| PubEncTerm (t: Term) (k: Name).

Definition TermSet: Type := Ensemble Term.


Inductive dy : TermSet -> Term -> Prop:=
| ax {X: TermSet} {t: Term} (inH: In Term X t) : dy X t
| pk {X: TermSet} {k: Name} (kH: dy X (PrivKeyTerm k)) : dy X (PubKeyTerm k)
                                                           
| splitL {X: TermSet} {t1 t2: Term} (splitH: dy X (PairTerm t1 t2)) : dy X t1
| splitR {X: TermSet} {t1 t2: Term} (splitH: dy X (PairTerm t1 t2)) : dy X t2
| pair {X: TermSet} {t1 t2: Term} (tH: dy X t1) (uH: dy X t2) : dy X (PairTerm t1 t2)
                                                               
| sdec {X: TermSet} {t: Term} {k: Name} (encH: dy X (PrivEncTerm t k)) (kH: dy X (PrivKeyTerm k)): dy X t
| senc {X: TermSet} {t: Term} {k: Name} (tH: dy X t) (kH: dy X (PrivKeyTerm k)) : dy X (PrivEncTerm t k)
                                                                                     
| adec {X: TermSet} {t: Term} {k: Name} (encH: dy X (PubEncTerm t k)) (keyH: dy X (PrivKeyTerm k)): dy X t
| aenc {X: TermSet} {t: Term} {k: Name} (tH: dy X t) (kH: dy X (PubKeyTerm k)) : dy X (PubEncTerm t k).

Now, I'm trying to prove a Normalisation property for this, as defined here. (Ignore the pub).
Normalisation property
In trying to do this, I'm trying to implement a way of showing that a proof is normal. However, I am failing at this.
There are two ways I've been trying going about it. One is by building a relation on proofs called Normal, and trying to define constructors on the relation. I've been trying to build something of the sort
Inductive Normal {X: TermSet} {t: Term} : dy X t -> Prop := (* .. *),

However, I'm having trouble with this, particularly when I'm trying to implement any of the constructor rules, since Coq cant unify, say (PrivEncTerm t k) with the specific {t: Term} in the argument (used in dy X t).
The other approach I've been trying is defining a computation that calculates whether a proof is normal, however, I'm getting some weird type error when I do this.
Fixpoint isNormal {X: TermSet} {t: Term} (proof: dy X t) : bool := 
  match proof with
  | pair p1 p2 => andb (isNormal p1) (isNormal p2)
  | senc pt pK => andb (isNormal pt) (isNormal pK)
  | aenc pt pK => andb (isNormal pt) (isNormal pK)
  | pk pK => isNormal pK
                      
  | ax _ => true
  | splitL p =>  andb (isNormal p) (match p with | pair _ _ => false
                                           | senc _ _ => false
                                           | aenc _ _ => false
                                           | pk _ => false
                                         
                                           | splitL _ => true
                                           | splitR _ => true
                                           | sdec _ _ => true
                                           | adec _ _ => true
                                                           | ax _ => true
                                   end)
  | splitR p => andb (isNormal p) (match p with | pair _ _ => false
                                           | senc _ _ => false
                                           | aenc _ _ => false
                                           | pk _ => false
                                           | _ => true
                                   end)
  | sdec pe pK => andb (isNormal pe) (andb (isNormal pK) (match pe with | pair _ _ => false
                                                                   | senc _ _ => false
                                                                   | aenc _ _ => false
                                                                   | pk _ => false
                                                                   | _ => true
                                                          end))
  | adec pe pK => andb andb (isNormal pe) (andb (isNormal pK) (match pe with | pair _ _ => false
                                                                        | senc _ _ => false
                                                                        | aenc _ _ => false
                                                                        | pk _ => false
                                                                        | _ => true end))
end.

Weird Type Error
The "true of type bool" in question is in the last branch (the ax branch) of the match in the splitL case.
I have no idea how to resolve this, when I feel like the function itself is ok. Any advice on either of the two approaches would be really appreciated.
EDIT: I have understood the cause of the Weird Type Error, courtesy of @pierre-courtieu , however, fixing it by changing the definition of dy to return a Type isn't what I want. While in the meantime I'll be changing isNormal to return a Prop (which isnt working yet), any help on forming an inductive definition would be appreciated!

Your problem here (besides some superficial syntactic ones that the other answer already pointed out) is that you need to make a design decision: Do your derivations dy have "meaningful content" besides the question of whether they exist or not, and how meaningful is it?
If your proofs have meaningful content that you want to compute with; or if you want to define predicates about the "shape" of proofs, then you most likely want your proofs to be in Type. This means that Coq treats them as "data" and you can use it to write recursive functions on.
At first glance, this seems to be the case here. Unfortunately, this means that several things become more annoying. For example, Coq refuses to let you use them in "propositional" connectives like conjunction of disjunction. Instead, you need to use the corresponding connectives in Type, like pairs and sum types. You also need to have a good grasp of the elimination restriction (which is what prevents you from eliminating Props into Type) and its exceptions, in order to see ahead of time that your proof strategy can work. Also, your proof goals now all become exercises in dependently typed programming, which could potentially get very tricky.
An alternative that might work better here is to define (in Prop) a new judgment that corresponds to "normal form proofs," and then prove that both kinds of derivations are equivalent (which entails proving some sort of "normalization" procedure).
Which option is better is hard to say, that depends on what your future plans with this development are.

Right, I had considered making an alternate NormalProof judgement, but would that be feasible? There are places where I would have to say "Normal_proofs constructed with normal_split need a Normal_proof constructed with normal_ax, normal_sdec... etc. Can I use these other constructors within the same inductive definition? I don't see how else I'd go about it.

Sounds like it's not entirely trivial, but that's the joy of formalizing things like that. Looks like there's actually several different kind of "normal proofs," and you can only plug certain ones in other ones? Or maybe normal proofs have a parameter that can be used to outlaw certain constructors sometimes? You'd need to think deeply about that to find out.

I guess that is how the original proof goes. Doesn't it? The fact that you can or cannot define normal proofs as the result of a function or as a (functional) inductive should not really change the shape of your proof.

(please always give a content which compiles until the error you want to point out).
Two remarks:
First you cannot define a function which computes on (dy which is in) Prop to produce something in (bool which is in) Type. So your definition will fail even if you fix the error message you see. See below.
Second you are defining a dependent pattern matching and the type checker needs a bit help to figure out the type of the branches. Here a simple return bool seems to do the trick. But as you can see your definition fails because of "incorrect elimination". So either you turn your ty into Type instead of Prop, or you define isNormal as an inductive. Let me mention a third option: you return True and False instead of true and false (this way you eliminate from Ptop to Prop) but this is rather confusing for beginners (and not so useful compared to the inductive).

Require Import Ensembles.

Definition Var := nat.
Definition Name := nat.

Inductive Term: Type :=
| VarTerm (v: Var)
| PrivKeyTerm (k: Name)
| PubKeyTerm (k: Name)
| PairTerm (t1 t2: Term)
| PrivEncTerm  (t: Term) (k: Name)
| PubEncTerm (t: Term) (k: Name).

Definition TermSet: Type := Ensemble Term.


Inductive dy : TermSet -> Term -> Prop := (* change to Type here to solve the error below*)
| ax {X: TermSet} {t: Term} (inH: In Term X t) : dy X t
| pk {X: TermSet} {k: Name} (kH: dy X (PrivKeyTerm k)) : dy X (PubKeyTerm k)
                                                            
| splitL {X: TermSet} {t1 t2: Term} (splitH: dy X (PairTerm t1 t2)) : dy X t1
| splitR {X: TermSet} {t1 t2: Term} (splitH: dy X (PairTerm t1 t2)) : dy X t2
| pair {X: TermSet} {t1 t2: Term} (tH: dy X t1) (uH: dy X t2) : dy X (PairTerm t1 t2)
                                                                   
| sdec {X: TermSet} {t: Term} {k: Name} (encH: dy X (PrivEncTerm t k)) (kH: dy X (PrivKeyTerm k)): dy X t
| senc {X: TermSet} {t: Term} {k: Name} (tH: dy X t) (kH: dy X (PrivKeyTerm k)) : dy X (PrivEncTerm t k)
                                                                                     
| adec {X: TermSet} {t: Term} {k: Name} (encH: dy X (PubEncTerm t k)) (keyH: dy X (PrivKeyTerm k)): dy X t
| aenc {X: TermSet} {t: Term} {k: Name} (tH: dy X t) (kH: dy X (PubKeyTerm k)) : dy X (PubEncTerm t k).




Fixpoint isNormal {X: TermSet} {t: Term} (proof: dy X t) : bool := 
  match proof with
  | pair p1 p2 => andb (isNormal p1) (isNormal p2)
  | senc pt pK => andb (isNormal pt) (isNormal pK)
  | aenc pt pK => andb (isNormal pt) (isNormal pK)
  | pk pK => isNormal pK
                      
  | ax _ => true
  | splitL p =>
      andb (isNormal p)
        (match p return bool with
         | pair _ _ => false
         | senc _ _ => false
         | aenc _ _ => false
         | pk _ => false
         | splitL _ => true
         | splitR _ => true
         | sdec _ _ => true
         | adec _ _ => true
         | ax _ => true
         end)
  | splitR p =>
      andb (isNormal p)
        (match p with | pair _ _ => false
                 | senc _ _ => false
                 | aenc _ _ => false
                 | pk _ => false
                 | _ => true
         end)
  | sdec pe pK =>
      andb (isNormal pe)
        (andb (isNormal pK)
           (match pe with | pair _ _ => false
                     | senc _ _ => false
                     | aenc _ _ => false
                     | pk _ => false
                     | _ => true
            end))
  | adec pe pK =>
      andb
        (andb (isNormal pe)
           (andb (isNormal pK) (match pe with | pair _ _ => false
                                         | senc _ _ => false
                                         | aenc _ _ => false
                                         | pk _ => false
                                         | _ => true end)))
  end.



Thanks for the feedback, I'm still new to Coq but I understand the error now. Unfortunately I cannot convert the Type to a Prop, since dy X t is a proposition that I need to be able to use in conjunction with other propositions (when proving Monotonicity for example). As mentioned in the post, I was trying an Inductive definition of Normal too but failing, so any guidance towards a successful Inductive definition will be really appreciated. (I will try the Prop to Prop approach for now).

Your "return True or False" option does not work. The restriction you mention allows you to eliminate a Prop only when constructing an object whose type is in Prop, i.e. when proving another proposition. But note that the type of True is not in Prop (it is Prop, but not in Prop, rather in Type). This is unsurprising, since the point of the restriction is (among other things) to prevent you from making statements about the shape of proofs that could become contradictory when one assumes proof irrelevance.

Goor point. I remove that part.
